# Unaligned load. What is the address of the word loaded into R1?

Tags: assembly, mips

Could someone please explain how the OR of register R2 and R3 results in the address value 15 for register R1?

```
R5 = 12 
lw R2, 0(R5)
lw R3, 4(R5)
sll R2, R2, 24
srl R3, R3, 8
or R1, R2, R3
```

Comment: `lw` is a load from memory. We can't tell what `R2` and `R3` will be without knowing the content of memory referenced.

Comment: No, as @Jester says, given this incompleteness, how could anyone answer what is at memory locations 12 through 19?

Comment: The question was "What is the address of the word loaded into R1". The answer is 15, but I dont understand how you can know that.

Comment: No word is loaded in to `R1`, and, hence there is ***no address*** for the word loaded into `R1` -- the question doesn't make sense -- it is a non-sequitur, the terms are not in agreement!

Comment: `R1` is assigned a value by an arithmetic operation (logical OR), not a memory operation.  Arithmetic operations have sources, not (memory) addresses.  The value of `R1` after this OR depends on the values of `R2` and `R3`, and, the values in `R2` and `R3`, (assuming `R5` holds 12) depend on memory locations 12-19, *which are not shown here*.

Comment: It would seem that you have some fundamental misunderstanding of the scenario or or mis-transcription of the original question.  I would suggest you return to the original text where you found the question, and re-read it with the above in mind.

Comment: The original question was "This code does an unaligned load. What is the address of the word loaded into R1?" and the code was the one pasted above. We were given the alternatives: a)13, b)14, c)15 or d)16 and answer c)15 was marked as the correct one.

Comment: those opposite shifts + OR look like a rotate (by 8 bytes), if that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should apparently be like this:

```
R5 = 12 
lw R2, 0(R5) -> [12,13,14,15]
lw R3, 4(R5) ->[16,17,18,19], offset 4 bytes from value stored in R5, i.e. 12
sll R2, R2, 24 ->[15,0,0,0], shift left 3 bytes (24/8=3)
srl R3, R3, 8 -> [0,16,17,18], shift left 1 byte
or R1, R2, R3 ->[15,16,17,18], "merge the arrays"
```

So the word starts at index or address value 15.

Comment: Yup, nice writeup with comments; that's exactly what I described in my answer but in more detail.  I think this is for big-endian MIPS (unlike MARS), so the highest address byte of the `R2` load is in the *low* 8 bits of the register.  (And should be the high 8 bits of the unaligned word at `3(R15)`.)

Answer (score 0):

Those opposite shifts + OR appear to be implementing a sliding window onto the 8-byte pair of words, implementing an unaligned load from R5+3.

We left-shift it by 24 bits = 3 bytes before merging with the low 3 bytes of `4(R5).